# Wifi doesn't disconnect even after being removed from wifi network suggestion. How to disconnect user after removing wifi from network suggestion?

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am trying to connect and disconnect form a wifi programmatically in android(kotlin).
I am able to connect user to wifi using **WifiNetworkSuggestion**.
Now when I try to disconnect the user from the wifi(which was joined using our app WifiNetworkSuggestion), I am unable to disconnect user even after removing the user form suggestion list. Below is the code I am using :

```
fun disconnectFromNetwork(ssid: String, password: String) {
    val wifiManager: WifiManager = this.applicationContext.getSystemService(
        Context.WIFI_SERVICE
    ) as WifiManager
    when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
            val suggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                .setSsid(ssid)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                .build()
            val suggestionsList: MutableList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> = ArrayList()
            suggestionsList.add(suggestion)
            wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList)
        }
        else -> {
        }
    }
}
```

According to android documentation.

> [removeNetworkSuggestions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List%3Candroid.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion%3E)):
> Remove some or all of the network suggestions that were previously
> provided by the app. If one of the suggestions being removed was used
> to establish connection to the current network, then the device will
> immediately disconnect from that network.

But the wifi connection persist even after removing the wifi from suggestion.
How to disconnect user after removing wifi from network suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This issue only seems to exist on API level 29. It works as intended for android with API level greater than 29.